# WSDL2Java certificate error

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java, sslhandshakeexception

Using the WSDL2Java.bat included in Apache Axis2 to generate .java files from an online SOAP WSDL service, however I get an error about some certificate. I have no idea where this is coming from, it should work according to the instructions I was given.

```
Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Users\****\Downloads\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException
: Error parsing WSDL
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerat
ionEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.Validator
Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPath
BuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unk
nown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerat
ionEngine.java:99)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Sour
ce)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
 Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
```

Anyone got any hint on what the issue could be or where I should start looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to generate Java classes using a WSDL from an HTTPS URL. It fails when it is trying to validate the certificate.

Try to access the WSDL from your browser and it should give you a warning.

You can save the WSDL to your local directory and try to run WSDL2Java for that file.

However you might get similar errors when you access the web service via stub, if the endpoint is also an HTTPS URL.

Comment: Thanks, yes I got it working by saving it manually to a .wsdl-file. However I also managed to get it working by adding the correct certificate, running "set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Path/to/certificate" and then generate the Java files from HTTPS source.